# Constants in an FXML file

Tags: variables, javafx, constants, fxml

Couldn't find any examples on this. How do I define constants in an FXML file?

For example (where `CONTENT_SPACING` is the constant I want to create):

```
<VBox fx:controller="myapp.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" spacing="20">
    <fx:define>
        <Double fx:id="CONTENT_SPACING" fx:value="200"/>
    </fx:define>

    <VBox fx:id="content" spacing="$CONTENT_SPACING">
        <!-- My window contents would go here -->
    </VBox>
</VBox>
```

My code would benefit in readability if this was possible. Thanks!

Comment: I think this works if you correct the syntax: `spacing="${CONTENT_SPACING}"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, this is a bit embarrassing. It was valid FXML all along, but my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) keeps telling me it's not. The code itself runs fine.

[image: screenshot]

I'll go file a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140244).

Edit: Bug is fixed.

Comment: I'm not actually sure it should work though. Does IntelliJ still complain if you include the `{}` in the expression?

Comment: @James_D IntelliJ complains with or without the `{}`. But the code runs fine both with and without the braces. No complaints from the VM, only IntelliJ.

Comment: Same issue with IntelliJ 14.1.2. I couldn't find any bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Any way to have CONTENT_SPACING defined in the controller?